# How to use Android REGEX with Pattern and Matcher Classes?

Tags: java, android, regex

I have the following code:

```
String example = "<!--§FILES_SECTION§\n" +
                "Example line one\n" +
                "Example line two\n" +
                "§FILES_SECTION§-->";

        String myPattern = ".*?FILES_SECTION.*?\n(.*?)\n.*?FILES_SECTION.*?";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(myPattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(example);

        if ( m.matches() )
            Log.d("Matcher", "PATTERN MATCHES!");
        else
            Log.d("MATCHER", "PATTERN DOES NOT MATCH!");
```

Why does it always return "PATTERN DOES NOT MATCH?"

Comment: Your pattern is not even close to what you want. I recommend you should more about regex before: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, the . does not match line breaks. You would need to add a regex option so that it does:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(myPattern,Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Answer (score 3):

m.matches() will only return true if the entire string matches. Use m.find() instead, and it should work better!

Comment: But shouldn't the entire string match the regular expression? I think it should!

Anyway, I have tried using a while (m.find) and it doesn't even loop once so I think it's a different problem!

Comment: Maybe I was a bit unclear. matches() implicitly adds "^" and "$" at the beginning and end of your pattern, so your string won't match since it begins with "<!--" and ends with "-->". Maybe a combination of find() and arc's solution will work? Edit: sorry, I read your pattern wrong. Like Caner says, it looks a bit wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

First, as arc has said, . won't match to \n unless you activate Pattern.DOTALL, and as Petter M, you should use m.find(), or else it won't match.

Then, you could use this other expression, if, by any reason, you cannot work with Pattern.DOTALL.

FILES_SECTION(?:.|\s)*FILES_SECTION

(Note I'm using a non-capturing group for the characters between the FILES_SECTION delimiters).

Comment: Also, you could use your expression with matches() enabling Pattern.DOTALL AND removing all the ? characters from the expression. Remember a? matches a between 0 and 1 times, and a* matches a between 0 and n times... so writing something like a*? is kind of moot. This way, your own expression could be simplified to: ".*FILES_SECTION.*FILES_SECTION.*", provided you use the Pattern.DOTALL. Anyway, I think that this expression could be too broad. :)

Comment: Another way you could avoid DOTALL would be using this character class: [\d\D]+

That would match anything that is either a digit or not a digit.. ie anything at all