# How to search for and replace a whole phrase in a string array?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am trying to search a string for a phrase of words, and then replace the phrase with a blank space. Here is my code:

```
  public void convertToNotes() {
    classNotes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.class_notes);
    className = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.class_name);
    verifyTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    verifyTextView.setSingleLine(false);

    conversionText = classNotes.getText().toString();
    String[] result = conversionText.split(".");


    for (int a = 0; a < result.length; a++) {

        result[a] = result[a].replaceAll("forget"+ "about"+ "that", "");
        result[a] = result[a].replaceAll("important", " <br><u>IMPORTANT</u>");
        }
    verifyTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(Arrays.toString(result)));
 }
```

I have also tried :

```
result[a] = result[a].replaceAll("forget about that", "");
```

But the phrase is still not removed.

Comment: `replaceAll` read the documentation about that.

Comment: What's your input? What are the contents of `result[]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to split your string in order to replace elements.
You can do something like:

```
conversionText = conversionText.replaceAll("forget" /*or other regex*/, "");
verifyTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(conversionText));
```

If you need to keep the splitting for some reason and If you have troubles with regex, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585859/how-to-use-android-regex-with-pattern-and-matcher-classes).